# Joining ManyToMany fields with prefetch_related in Django

Tags: python, django, orm

I may be missing something obvious, but I'm having trouble getting a join on a ManyToMany field to work in a Django app. I have two models:

```
class Area(models.Model):
    name = CharField(...)

class Role(models.Model):
    name = CharField(...)
    areas = ManyToManyField('Area', ...)
```

My goal is to have the equivalent of this query:

```
select a.name, r.name
from area a
join area_role ar on ar.area_id = a.id
join role r on ar.role_id = r.id
order by a.name, r.name
```

The resulting data set would look like:

```
Area    Role
---------------------
A       My Role
A       Your Role
A       Yo Mamas Role
B       My Role
B       Some Other Role
```

As you can see in the example, the **My Role** item appears twice, once for each area. I know I could get the list of areas and then get a list of roles for each (resulting in N+1 queries), but I'd like to be efficient about it if possible. As such, I found that [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) might be what I wanted to use. When I use this, however, I end up with all Area values as **None**. Here's what I tried:

```
rqs = ( Role.objects.filter(areas__id__in=[1,2,3])
        .prefetch_related(areas).order_by('areas__name', 'name') )

for r in rqs:
    print("Area Name: " + str(r.areas.name))
    print("Role Name: " + str(r.name))
```

The role names come along for the ride correctly, but the area names do not. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: unrelated: why do you put `Area` between quotes in `areas = ManyToManyField('Area', ...)`?

Comment: `print("Area Name: " + str(r.areas__name))` did you mean `print("Area Name: " + str(r.areas.name))`?

Comment: @Pynchia he could use Area without quotes in this case, since Area is defined before Role model. If Area was defined after Role, quotes would be required. [Full explanation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#lazy-relationships)

Comment: @danielcorreia Yes, I meant `r.areas.name`. Not sure how those double underscores got there...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It isn't possible to access `r.areas__name` for a Role `r`. You still have to access the roles via `r.areas.all()`. However, by using `prefetch_related`, you fetch all the related objects in one extra query, instead of O(n) queries.

Since you want to order by area name, you should probably use the `Area` model for your queryset, then loop through the related roles.

```
areas = Area.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 2, 3]).order_by('name').prefetch_related('role_set')

for area in areas:
    roles = area.role_set.all()
    for role in roles:
        print area.name, roles.name
```

That should give you the ordering you want, as long as the `Role` model is ordered by `name` by default. If not, you could use a [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) object to order the related queryset.