# Django Prefetch Related Issue - Understand it correctly

Tags: python, html, sql, django, prefetch

I do have the following Issue - I want to display all of the bundles with their component relations in a template:

Here is my ORM-Model:

```
    class Component(models.Model):
        plenty_var_number = models.CharField(max_length=120, default=None, unique=True, null=True)
        plenty_var_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, default=None, unique=True)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=False)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.category.name} - {self.plenty_var_number}"


    class Bundle(models.Model):
        active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        plenty_var_number = models.CharField(max_length=120, default=None, unique=True, null=True)
        plenty_var_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, default=None)
        car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
        # m2m defined by BundleComponentRelation
        components = models.ManyToManyField(Component, through="BundleComponentRelation")
        linked_to_plenty = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=-1.00)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)


    class BundleComponentRelation(models.Model):
        component = models.ForeignKey(Component, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
        bundle = models.ForeignKey(Bundle, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
        qty = models.IntegerField(default=1)
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

I have played around with `select_related` and `prefetch_related` in my view to pass them via context to the template to display it for my users:

html-template:

```
                    {% for bundle in bundles %}
                        <tr>
                            <td><p class="fw-bold">{{ bundle.plenty_var_number }}</p></td>
                            <td>{{ bundle.price }}</td>

                            <td><p class="fw-bolder mb-0">{{ bundle.car }}</p>
                                <p class="mb-0">{{ bundle.car.roof_type }}</p>
                                <p class="mb-0">BJ: {{ bundle.car.production_start }}
                                    - {{ bundle.car.production_end }}</p>
                            </td>

                            {# Bundle Component Relations here #}


                            <td style="font-size: 1em;">
                                <a href={% url "edit_bundle" bundle.pk %}><i
                                        class="fas fa-xl fa-edit "></i></a>
                                <a href={% url "sync_bundle" bundle.pk %}><i
                                        class="fas fa-xl fa-sync "></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
def bundle_view(request):
    bundles = Bundle.objects.prefetch_related('components').all()
    print(bundles[0].components)
    return render(request, "all_bundles.html", context={"bundles": bundles})
```

The output of `print(bundles[0].components)` is `bundle.Component.None`

I understood the forward usage of `select_related` but I do have trouble understanding the reverse thinking of the `prefetch_related` in my situation.

I think my problem is the lookup syntax of `prefetch_related`, but I might be wrong here.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I tried:

```
         {% for bundle in bundles %}
                        <tr>
                            <td><p class="fw-bold">{{ bundle.plenty_var_number }}</p></td>
                            <td>{{ bundle.price }}</td>

                            <td><p class="fw-bolder mb-0">{{ bundle.car }}</p>
                                <p class="mb-0">{{ bundle.car.roof_type }}</p>
                                <p class="mb-0">BJ: {{ bundle.car.production_start }}
                                    - {{ bundle.car.production_end }}</p>
                            </td>

                            {% for comp_rel in bundle.components.all %}
                                {{ comp_rel }}
                            {% endfor %}
                            <td style="font-size: 1em;">
                                <a href={% url "edit_bundle" bundle.pk %}><i
                                        class="fas fa-xl fa-edit "></i></a>
                                <a href={% url "sync_bundle" bundle.pk %}><i
                                        class="fas fa-xl fa-sync "></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
```

I wanted to get only the related components to the currently iterated bundle. The problem I get here is that the template triggers the database again:

[monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUrQZ.png)

Simply using the `bundle.component` in the template led to

[ManyRelatedManager object is not iterable TypError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXysn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is because the `__str__` of the `Component` accesses the `Category`, hence for each `{{ comp_rel }}`, you render, it will make an extra query.

You should use a [**`Prefetch`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) to fetch the `Category`s in the same query as the one where you fetch the `Component`s:

```
from app_name.models import Bundle, Component
from django.db.models import Prefetch

def bundle_view(request):
    bundles = Bundle.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('components', Component.objects.select_related('category'))
    )
    return render(request, 'all_bundles.html', {'bundles': bundles})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your prefetch_related, but the way you want to access these objects, you should do `bundles[0].components.all()` because objects fetched with reverse relation can be accessed same way as M2M fields

Comment: Thanks alot, and how can I use them in my template then? just with `bundle.components.all` and iterating over it?

Comment: In Django templates you can just use bundle.components and iterate over it

Comment: Please check my original post again, I tried your solution but stumbled upon a new issue there.

Comment: Have you tried iterating over bundle.components without .all ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it must be `prefetch_related`? I think it must be `select_related`.

I think you should use `Bundle.objects.select_related('components').all()` and `Component.objects.prefetch_related('bundle_set').all()` with your models. But I'm not sure.

And what about template error - you shoud use `{% for component in bundle.components.all %}` in template.

And [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112924/joining-manytomany-fields-with-prefetch-related-in-django) same problem, mb will helpfull.